# React unable select multiple checkboxes after selected from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have two array that as Plant list & saved plant :

```
const dataPlant = [
{ id: 1, name: 'AAA' },
{ id: 2, name: 'BBB' },
{ id: 3, name: 'CCC' },
{ id: 4, name: 'DDD' },
{ id: 4, name: 'EEE' }
];

const savedPlant = ['AAA', 'CCC'];
```

Given `checked: true` for dataPlant that has same value from savedPlant,

There's a form to edit data, it has field to choose multiple options like this
[image: checboxes],

I put checked value for the saved option, but couldn't select other options, and I need to get ID from the selected option. help me to get selected ID values, I've replicate my code on [this Stackblitz Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-d6tpbv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of unneeded definitions in your code.

1. Your dataPlant array is a constant. You can put it outside.
2. You wrote a complex function to find the selected items from line 44 on - why would you do it? You actually have your array of selected items already defined with your `plantIds` state. You can simply use this to check whether the listed item is selected or not in order to put the right checkbox value.
3. You mixed up a bit the id and the name. In the example below I used the string as the value. You can do similar with the id if you prefer that.
4. Still, there is a space for improvements.

This will work:

```
const dataPlant = [
  { id: 1, name: 'AAA' },
  { id: 2, name: 'BBB' },
  { id: 3, name: 'CCC' },
  { id: 4, name: 'DDD' },
  { id: 5, name: 'EEE' }
];

export default function App() {
  const [plantIds, setPlantIds] = useState(['AAA', 'BBB']);
  
  const handleSelectPlant = e => {
    const check = e.target.checked;
    const checkedPlant = e.target.value;

    if (check) {
      setPlantIds(prev => [...prev, checkedPlant]);
    } else {
      setPlantIds(plantIds.filter(plantName => plantName !== checkedPlant));
    }
  };

  const selectPlant = () => {
    const plantList = dataPlant.map(plant => (
      <div className="checkbox-wrap" key={plant.id}>
        <Label check>
          <Input
            type="checkbox"
            value={plant.name}
            onChange={e => handleSelectPlant(e)}
            checked={plantIds.includes(plant.name)}
          />{' '}
          <span>{plant.name}</span>
        </Label>
      </div>
    ));

    return (
      <FormGroup check className="pl-0 pb-1">
        <Label>Select Plant</Label>
        {plantList}
        <br />
        <br />
        Selected plant IDs : {plantIds}
      </FormGroup>
    );
  };
  return <div>{selectPlant()}</div>;
}
```

Comment: much simpler and really thanks for the notes!

Answer (score 1):

In the function `selectPlant`, you are using `savedPlant` to determine whether the plant is checked or not instead of using the variable `plantIds` where you save the checked plants. So you should use the variable `plantIds` inside this function and delete the variable `savedPlant`, because both variables are doing the same job.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState, Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  Button,
  Modal,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalBody,
  FormGroup,
  InputGroup,
  InputGroupAddon,
  InputGroupText,
  Input,
  Label
} from 'reactstrap';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const dataPlant = [
    { id: 1, name: 'AAA' },
    { id: 2, name: 'BBB' },
    { id: 3, name: 'CCC' },
    { id: 4, name: 'DDD' },
    { id: 5, name: 'EEE' }
  ];

  const [plantIds, setPlantIds] = useState([1, 3]);
  const handleSelectPlant = e => {
    const check = e.target.checked;
    const checkedPlant = parseInt(e.target.value);
    if (check) {
      setPlantIds(prev => [...prev, checkedPlant]);
    } else {
      const index = plantIds.indexOf(checkedPlant);
      if (index > -1) {
        const plantsIdUpdated = [...plantIds];
        plantsIdUpdated.splice(index, 1);
        setPlantIds(plantsIdUpdated);
      }
    }
  };

  const selectPlant = () => {
    let plantList = null;
    if (dataPlant) {
      dataPlant.forEach(function(perm) {
        perm.checked = false;
        plantIds.forEach(function(id) {
          if (id === perm.id) {
            perm.checked = true;
          }
        });
      });

      plantList = dataPlant.map(plant => (
        <div className="checkbox-wrap" key={plant.id}>
          <Label check>
            <Input
              type="checkbox"
              value={plant.id}
              onChange={e => handleSelectPlant(e)}
              checked={plant.checked}
            />{' '}
            <span>{plant.name}</span>
          </Label>
        </div>
      ));
    }
    return (
      <FormGroup check className="pl-0 pb-1">
        <Label>Select Plant</Label>
        {plantList}
        <br />
        <br />
        Selected plant IDs : {plantIds}
      </FormGroup>
    );
  };
  return <div>{selectPlant()}</div>;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ngpyqc?file=src%2FApp.js